# Proving $\sqrt[y]{\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^y-1}$ is irrational when $y>2$ is an integer and $x$ is rational and positive

Tags: number-theory

How would one prove$$\sqrt[y]{\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^y-1}$$is irrational 
when $y>2$ is an integer and $x$ is rational and positive?

I can prove it when $y=3$, and thought maybe one could use induction from there, but I was unable to prove the general case.

Comment: hint - i'd write a truly wonderful proof here, but there's not enough space in this comment section...

Comment: Given rational $z>1$ there is a rational $x>0$ so that $z=\frac{x+1}x.$ So this is equivalent to asking for rational $z>1,$ rational $w$ and integer $x>2$ such that $$z^x =1+w^x.$$ This can be seen as equivalent to Fermat’s Last Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x = p/q$ in lowest terms, and simplify. The denominator will be a power of $p$, the numerator an integer. It should be easy to prove it isn't a perfect $y$ power.